# Is $f(z)=z+1/z$ analytic?

Tags: complex-analysis

Is $f(z)=z+1/z$ analytic ?

Here $z$ is analytic and $1/z$ is analytic on $\mathbb{C}-\{0\}$, so their sum is analytic on $\mathbb{C}-\{0\}$.

Comment: But $z$ is analytic.

Comment: @coffeemath, sorry my mistake

Comment: If you add a non-analytic function to its negative, then their sum is zero which **is** analytic. So the proposed argument is invalid and fails to answer the question.

Comment: @Somos yet another error in this silly thread. Somos, 0 is holomorphic, in fact, f(z)=c is holomorphic for all constant c∈ℂ. If you add a holomorphic function g(z) to its negative −g(z), you get g_plus_negg(z)=0, which is NOT analytic (derivative of g_plus_negg(z) is 0) though all the functions are still holomorphic

Comment: since 1/z is not equal to −z,   f(z) = z + 1/z is not "0 for all z" or "constant for all z" therefore its derivative is not 0 therefore it is analytic (analytic means holomorphic AND nonzero derivative)

Comment: unless f(z)=0 is considered analytic despite being a useless function whose derivative is 0 and who cannot make a conformal map, in which case forgive me for not being well versed in the terminology of complex analysis, im just a guy fooling aroud with e to the i π to be honest

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function is analytic on the domain $\mathbb C\setminus \{0\}$, which is the most reasonable domain for the function to be defined on. Indeed, on this domain both $z$ and $1/z$ are analytic and thus their sum is, too. Note that the function is undefined at $z=0$.

Answer (score 2):

$z$ is analytic.   $\dfrac 1z$ has a simple pole at $z=0$.  It is *meromorphic*, but not analytic.  Meremorphicity is a generalization of analyticity, from functions that equal their power series to functions that have a *Laurent series* (with possible negative power terms).

Now $z+\dfrac 1z$ is also meromorphic  but not analytic (since in fact we have $\dfrac {z^2+1}z$ and a simple pole at $z=0$).

Answer (score 2):

This question does not make sense until unless you specify the domain of definition.

The function is not analytic on $\mathbb{C}$ but it is analytic on $\mathbb{C}\setminus\{0\}$